# simple code, seemingly random result - is this due to a stale reference?

Tags: c++, vector, reference

The code below concerns a vector of vectors of int which consists of a single vector with two elements. The code is pretty self explanatory. I expect an output of 2 from each of the print statements, but the second print statement prints 6.

I'm guessing that this has something to do with the passing of references and the order in which things are constructed, but I can't explain it. Can you explain this output? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Permutation
{
    public:

    Permutation(const vector<vector<int> >& cycles) : _cycles(cycles)
    {}

    static Permutation foo()
    {
        vector<vector<int> > cycles = {{2,3}};

        assert(cycles.front().size() == 2); // foo seems to create the correct thing locally

        return Permutation(cycles);
    }

    const vector<vector<int> >& _cycles;
};


int main()
{    
    vector<vector<int> > cycles = {{2,3}};
    Permutation perm(cycles);
    cout << perm._cycles.front().size() << endl; // outputs 2, as expected

    cout << Permutation::foo()._cycles.front().size() << endl; // outputs 6, seems like garbage to me

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_cycles` holds a reference to the `cycles` in `foo`, which is dead as soon as `foo` returns.

Answer (score 3):

Your guess was mostly correct. It's not that the passing of references was a problem, is that after all the references got passed around, here, and there, and everywhere, the object that was referenced went out of scope and got destroyed, with the reference left hanging around. Using the reference at that point becomes undefined behavior.

When all is said and done, `_cycles` ends up being a reference to a function-scoped object from a function that has returned, thus destroying the object that was referenced. A simplified example of what you did:

```
int &foo()
{
    int bar=4;

    return bar;
}

void foobar()
{
    int &blah=foo();
}
```

`foo()` returned a reference to a function-scoped object that was already destroyed by the time `foo()` returned, so the returned reference is referring to an object that went out of scope and got destroyed. Using the reference is now undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In foo() you're allocating a Permutation object in the current stack frame and then returning to your caller, destroying the frame(i.e. going out scope). You could instead allocate the new Permutation object on the heap and return the pointer, keeping in mind you'll want to free it at some point if done in something besides an example that exits immediately.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Permutation
{
    public:

    Permutation(const vector<vector<int> >& cycles) : _cycles(cycles)
    {}

    static Permutation * foo()
    {
        vector<vector<int> > cycles = {{2,3}};

        assert(cycles.front().size() == 2); // foo seems to create the correct thing locally

        return new Permutation(cycles);
     }

    const vector<vector<int> >& _cycles;
};


int main()
{    
    vector<vector<int> > cycles = {{2,3}};
    Permutation perm(cycles);
    cout << perm._cycles.front().size() << endl; // outputs 2, as expected

    cout << Permutation::foo()->_cycles.front().size() << endl; // outputs 6, seems like garbage to me

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed the line:

const vector >& _cycles;

to

const vector > _cycles;

and everything worked fine!

Comment: That's because, instead of holding a reference to an object that may be destroyed, your code now contains a copy of that object, which will continue to exist after the original is destroyed (and be linked to lifetime of the `Permutations` object).    If you don't understand why that is so, avoid using class/struct members that are references.